# Convert TMainMenu to TActionBars

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe, converters

I have in a old project, standard menus on my forms. The menu items are populated by `TActions` that I have made using the `TActionManager`.

I am updating this old project and would now like to change the appearance of my menu to `XP Style` as set by the `TActionManager`, so it can match the `TToolBars` on my forms which have changed to `dsGradient`.

Is there a non lazy way of making this transformation?

Otherwise it means I have to manually go through my forms, remove the `TMainMenus`, drop a `TActionMainMenuBar` on the form and then begin creating the `TActionBars` to populate the menus again, which I will be honest with you right now I don't feel like spending so much time doing this.

So if there is a way to automate the conversion somehow I would be interested to know, then I don't have to spend so much time manually changing them.

Equally, if the above can be done without manually making the changes, I would be interested to see if it is possible to reverse convert, eg TActionBar menu to TMainMenu?

If I must do it manually then so be it, but if there is a quicker better option then I really would like to know.

Comment: Well I ended up making the transformation manually. Needless to say if there is an automated method out there I would still be interested in knowing it. Perhaps a tool to parse through the DFM of the form and make the required changes I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to study the following converter utilities by [ChoosPill](http://www.choosepill.com/index.htm) :

1. [TB2KImpTb97](http://www.choosepill.com/components/CPCTB2KImpTb97.zip)
2. [TB2KImport](http://www.choosepill.com/components/CPCTB2KImport.zip)

They are distributed in **source code** and support the **import** of all relevant *items* and *properties* from stock VCL components **TMainMenu, TPopupMenu, TMenuItem** and **TToolBar** to [Jordan Russel](http://www.jrsoftware.org/)'s famous **Toolbar97/Toolbar2000** components respectfully.

You can also consider to take a glimpse at **TBXLib** converter [source code](https://code.google.com/p/tbxlib/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FTools%2FConverter) .

You can also consider delving into TdxBarConverter's source code if you are a [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) registred user.

They can serve as a good starting point for you.

Comment: I don't have DevExpress but I will take a look at TBXLib ;)

Comment: I wish you good luck. It's nice to meet other enthusiast here on SO.